# How to turn off asking about scanner calibration in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, device

I have over 12 Brother DSMobile 600 scanners and Panasonic toughbook's CF-19 with Windows 7. I'm using each toughbook with scanners from this pool. I'm always switch toughbooks and scanners. Everything worked fine and never asked about calibration. But when i'm added new additional scanner, Windows started give me a message - In order to scan the scanner must first be calibrated. I'm doing this calibration and when i'm connecting another scanner it's again asking about calibration.

When I connecting new scanner system creates different hardware ID (USB\VID_04F9&PID_204E&REV_0703) that have another scanners (USB\VID_04F9&PID_2038&REV_0302) and device name looks like DSmobile 600 #2.

How to turn off asking about scanner calibration?